# Como seria um Processo de Desenvolvimento Ágil?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, metodologia, metodologia-ágil

Na empresa que trabalho ainda não adotamos uma metodologia final para utilizarmos, e estamos pensando de nos próximos projetos adotar o desenvolvimento ágil.

Como seria um processo ágil? Preciso criar um documento de requisitos com toda especificação em detalhes ou posso descrever em um `readme.md` e utilizar histórias de usuário para gerar nossas interações junto com o Scrum?

Comment: Acredito que seja "história" - http://wp.clicrbs.com.br/sualingua/2009/05/06/a-triste-historia-de-estoria/

Answer (score 10):

O [Manifesto Ágil](http://manifestoagil.com.br/) valoriza os seguintes itens:

> **Indivíduos e interação entre eles** mais que processos e ferramentas
>
> **Software em funcionamento** mais que documentação abrangente
>
> **Colaboração com o cliente** mais que negociação de contratos
>
> **Responder a mudanças** mais que seguir um plano
>
> *É importante deixar claro que os itens da direita não deixam de ser necessários, só são menos importantes que os itens da esquerda.*

O manifesto ainda possuí [seus princípios](http://manifestoagil.com.br/principios.html), mas a ideia principal por trás disso é trabalhar nos pontos onde os modelos convencionais mais falham.

**Deixar de lado documentações muito específicas** (que muitas vezes dizem como o programador deve fazer seu trabalho), **estimular a comunicação entre os membros do time** ao máximo (com reuniões diárias), **entender o que o cliente quer e ter um feedback constante** e **abraçar mudanças constantes**, sejam mudanças nos requisitos ou mudanças para trazer melhorias ao time.

Tentando responder à sua pergunta: **não importa de que forma você fará sua documentação**, **apenas não perca muito tempo nela**. Se preocupe mais em **entender o que o cliente quer** e **transparecer isso para o resto do time** (nem que seja necessário colocar o time e o cliente na mesma sala), seja no formato de histórias de usuários, em um documento no Word, um arquivo de texto ou vários Post-its organizados pela sala.

Como eu mencionei antes, o Manifesto Ágil apresenta vários princípios e tudo isso pode parecer muito abstrato no papel.

Por isso, recomendo muito que você assista [esses vídeos sobre Extreme Programming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_ktqVPO4zY&list=PL66584479A168CC00), do [Vinícius Teles](http://viniciusteles.com.br/) no TDC de 2008.
Não estou recomendando que você aplique Extreme Programming, mas acho que explicação do Vinícius (e suas ótimas e hilárias analogias) podem te ajudar muito, assim como já me ajudaram.

Comment: Agradeço! Vou ver com certeza!

Answer (score 8):

primeiramente, optando ou não pela metodologia de desenvolvimento ágil, acredito que o seu projeto, deva ter a documentação de especificação de requisitos, por mínima que ela seja, sem muitos detalhes.

Ao contrário do que muitos pensam, que metodologia ágil consta em "*pular, ou diminuir*" a parte da chata da "*documentação*", o desenvolvimento ágil não é isso.

Resumidamente falando, o desenvolvimento ágil, o scrum por exemplo, consta em pegar o projeto como um todo, e dividi-lo em partes, como chamamos de Sprints, que é um determinado tempo onde vamos desenvolver um "entregável" da aplicação e entregar ao cliente. O Sprint geralmente e é recomendado que dure cerca de 2 a 4 semanas, este são divididos em estórias menores, essas estórias serão divididas em atividades menores ainda, de preferencia que possa ser desenvolvida e finalizada por um desenvolvedor em um dia, se demorar mais de um dia? Procurar ver se da para quebrá-la em duas ou mais atividades.

Entre outros detalhes, no *scrum* existe a cultura das reuniões ou cerimônias como são conhecidas, cerimonias diárias, de review e retrospectiva. E também os papeis do *scrum*, como o *PO (product owner)*, *Scrum Master* e *Time* (desenvolvedores).

Para mais detalhes, recomendo:

http://desenvolvimentoagil.com.br/scrum/

Comment: Será que um modelo de dados seria interessante antes do desenvolvimento de um software?

Comment: Com toda certeza sim @Kevin. Mas é possível desenhar e desenvolver um modelo de dados sem uma especificação minima do sistema?

Comment: Não. Estou tentando chegar a um modelo simples e que tenha uma quantidade de informação útil para a criação do software.

Estava pensando em ter o documento de requisitos como um documento que explicaria o que é o software e o que ele faz, juntamente com o modelo de dados e histórias de usuário para descrever os products backlogs.

Comment: Sim, é uma boa, você está indo no caminho certo. Seguindo essa sequencia de fazer o documento de requisitos sem precisar por muitos detalhes, depois o modelo de dados, e depois dividir em histórias e assim vão surgindo os detalhes que antes não haviam pensado. Por exemplo no documento de requisitos vc apenas define que vai haver um cadastro de usuário para logar no sistema, e posteriormente você detalha mais por exemplo, o usuário ira usar um username ou e-mail para autenticação?

Comment: Entendo, gostei desse tipo de abordagem. Não fica aquela coisa burocrática de só iniciar o desenvolvimento do software com toda a documentação necessária. Ter o mínimo para desenvolver e ir adicionando detalhes ao longo do desenvolvimento.

Uma coisa que fiquei em dúvida, já que os atributos como você citou no exemplo seriam adicionados posteriormente, seria uma boa adicionar o modelo de dados ? Uso o Visual Studio e ele me permite fazer a engenharia reversa (gerar o modelo de dados a partir das classes).

Comment: Pois, penso se seria melhor ter um modelo de dados antes de iniciar o projeto (para outras pessoas que não estão totalmente por dentro dos requisitos não vão ter a noção do que se precisa), ou detalho isso no documento de requisitos e faço a engenharia reversa?

Answer (score 3):

Um processo de desenvolvimento Ágil é aquele que observa o [Manifesto Ágil](http://www.agilemanifesto.org/), ou seja: respeita seus **valores** e aplica seus **princípios** em busca de seu **objetivo**.

E o objetivo é dado pelo primeiro princípio do Manifesto:

> Satisfazer o cliente através da entrega adiantada e contínua de software valioso.

Pode ser difícil ou mesmo inviável imprimir todos os valores e princípios do Manifesto na formalização de um processo, por isso espera-se que o resultado seja obtido da assimilação do Manifesto como uma **filosofia** ou **cultura**, mais do que do respeito a detalhados processos formais. Afinal o próprio Manifesto ***"valoriza mais indivíduos e interações do que processos e ferramentas"***.

Este, que é o primeiro valor do Manifesto, não deveria ser usado como argumento para não se utilizar processo nenhum, pois o próprio Manifesto nasceu a partir de processos que já eram empregados por seus autores na época.

Os exemplos mais célebres de processos Ágeis são o **Scrum** e o **Extreme Programming**, cada um deles bastante aberto e cheio de lacunas que permitem serem otimizados para cada ambiente (ou piorados para cada ambiente). O Scrum foca mais no nível de gestão do projeto e o XP se aprofunda mais na engenharia do software, promovendo ***"práticas ágeis"*** como *TDD* e *Continuous Integration*.

Existem, é claro, muitos outros processos Ágeis e cada dia alguém cria mais um.

Você também pode criar o seu. A rigor, basta respeitar os valores e aplicar os princípios através de práticas e comportamentos, com foco na *"satisfação do cliente através da entrega adiantada e contínua de software valioso"*.

Quanto ao detalhe de como deve ser a documentação, o Manifesto também fala sobre isso:

> Valorizamos mais software funcionando do que documentação abrangente.

Então seu processo Ágil deveria obserar este valor também.

**Em suma**, um requisito para se implantar um processo Ágil, seja de mercado ou proprietário, é estudar e assimilar o Manifesto, aceitando-o em sua essência.

Comment: Um processo ágil seria desenvolver um software de maneira rápida? É isso que entendo quando leio sobre Desenvolvimento Ágil.

Comment: @drmcarvalho Não, não seria. Podem existir outras maneiras ou outros motivos para um software ser desenvolvido rápido. Um processo Ágil é aquele que aplica o Manifesto. É claro que entregar o software certo e mais cedo é o grande objetivo, mas só é Ágil se a busca pelo objetivo se dá através da filosofia do Manifesto.

Answer (score 2):

Escrevi um artigo no meu [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/voc%C3%AA-quer-implementar-o-desenvolvimento-%C3%A1gil-ou-est%C3%A1-fugindo-silva/) sobre isso, acredito que pode ser útil para você tomando como base a primeira parte da sua pergunta.

### Você quer implementar o desenvolvimento ágil ou está simplesmente fugindo do desenvolvimento em cascata?

Implementar metodologia ágil em uma empresa que não nasceu assim não é fácil. Exige quebra de paradigmas e uma mudança radical na cultura e até mesmo na estrutura.

O que acontece na maioria dos casos é a empresa afirmar ser ágil, mas simplesmente não ser, contrariando todos os conceitos e regras de todos os manuais sobre ágil.

Para ser ágil a empresa primeiro precisa mudar sua cultura, adequar sua estrutura se necessário e em seguida, garantir que a equipe de desenvolvimento seja independente (esta a parte mais difícil).

Por experiência própria, lhe digo que esta migração não é fácil nem rápida. Talvez, seja até inviável, pois depende de uma série de fatores que vão além da fronteira do desenvolvimento (envolve outras lideranças de outras áreas).

Mas, vale a pena sim tentar ser ágil. Hoje o mercado pede isso. Quem consegue entregar valor ao cliente em menos tempo sai na frente da concorrência. Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Kevin,

Vou deixar alguns links do conteúdo necessário para você aprender sobre o ágil.

Leia este manifesto que vai te ajudar bastante(o site é meio retrô, mas é a melhor fonte para este teu questionamento): https://www.manifestoagil.com.br/

Começa pelos princípios: https://www.manifestoagil.com.br/principios.html

Quando terminar este estudo te recomendo em seguida o uso de um framework ágil.
Vou te recomendar o SCRUM. Contribuiu bastante com meu projeto e hoje nossas entregas geram muito mais valor ao cliente.

Site oficial com o guide do SCRUM: https://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html este material é ótimo e pode te ajudar até conseguir uma certificação caso tenha interesse.

Abraços